# Maatwebsite Excel load function not working

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

```
$file = $request->file('excel');
$reader = Excel::load($file->getRealPath())->get();
```

The following error appears:

> Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::load()

I am using Maatwebsite 3 in laravel 5.7

Comment: to get load or to get excel data as array you can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54902966/2815635)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `load` method has been removed in version 3.0 (may be re-added in 3.1). Please refer the [upgrade guide](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.0/getting-started/upgrade.html)

> ALL Laravel Excel 2.* methods are deprecated and will not be able to
>   use in 3.0 .

1. `Excel::load()` is removed and will not be re-added until 3.1
2. `Excel::create()` is removed and replaced by `Excel::download/Excel::store($yourExport)`
3. `v3.0` provides no convenience methods for styling, you are encouraged to use PhpSpreadsheets native methods.

Comment: what's the $yourExport here.

Answer (score 3):

The load method has been removed as quoted in the las post, however it has been already implemented in 3.1 version.

Excel::load() is removed and replaced by Excel::import($yourImport)

Checkout this [link](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/upgrade.html)

Personally, I ended it up using Excel::toColletion($file) though.

Answer (score 3):

^3.0 versions of maatwebsite/excel does not support loads.
Delete the `config/excel.php` file first .

Downgrade the maatwebsite/excel version by changing your composer.json
`"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1"`, to `"maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"`
perform `composer update`.

And if you get an error "Undefined class constant 'XLSX' in 2.1 version",this is what you have to do .

delete the `config/excel.php` before downgrading

then perform `composer update`.