# How to get excel to array in maatwebsite

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I am trying to convert an Excel file to an array using the latest version of [Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) (3.1.9)

The code below will download the file:

```
return Excel::download(new SalesOrderExport('columns'),'test.xlsx')
```

But I need to convert it to get an array only. I don't want to store this Excel data in a database at this point.

I tried with the code below but it did not work as the `load` method is not available in version 3.

```
Excel::load($request->file('sampledata'), function ($reader) {
    return response()->json($reader);
});
```

Please share your thoughts on how to get an array from Excel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I and @narayan tried hard to make requested excel file into array. Now I am able to get array properly with below code

```
$rows = Excel::toArray(new SalesOrderImport, $request->file('sampledata'));
```

In my SalesOrderExport class I have default function only, which is required as abstract method.

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\SalesOrder;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class SalesOrderExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {   
        return SalesOrder::all();
    }
}
```

My Controller code

```
public function importTest(Request $request)
{
    $rows = Excel::toArray(new SalesOrderImport, $request->file('sampledata'));
    return response()->json(["rows"=>$rows]);
}
```

And in HTML

```
<input class="" type="file" name="sampledata" id="sampledata">
```

I already created this export by

```
php artisan make:import SalesOrder
```

Attaching related images

[image][image]

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56522035/how-can-i-make-default-page-number-to-every-sheet-on-maatwebsitelaravel-excel

Answer (score 10):

I'm adding it on hope that someone could get another types of solution for this.
Version - `"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1"`

**In `Controller`**

```
$data = Excel::toArray(new UsersImport(), $request->file);
```

**In `UsersImport`**

```
<?php
    namespace App\Imports;
    use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

    class UsersImport implements ToCollection
    {
       public function collection(Collection $rows)
       {
       }
    }
```

**Json Array Result**

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
           0 => "+126785XXXXX"
           1 => "Jhon"
       ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
           0 => "+126784XXXXX"
           1 => "Doe"
       ]
  ]
```

**And One Bonus,**
Now suppose you just need the phone numbers, then make a custom array from that in controller-

```
$data = Excel::toArray(new UsersImport(), $request->file);
$phoneNumbersData= [];
foreach ($data[0] as $key => $value) {
  $phoneNumbersData[] = $value[0];
}
return $phoneNumbersData;
```

Hope, this will help someone.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some working examples based on importing a csv file using the usual file input element. In my case, once uploaded, the file is accessible through the request object as 'csv_file'.

```
public function importCSV(Request $request)
{
    // Get the csv rows as an array
    $theArray = Excel::toArray(new stdClass(), $request->file('csv_file'));

    // Get the csv rows as a collection
    $theCollection = Excel::toCollection(collect([]), $request->file('csv_file'));

    //etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried something like this and it worked perfectly;
in your import file do this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

public function collection(Collection $row)
{
    return $row;
}
```

Then in the controller, do this;

```
$row = Excel::toCollection(new CourseImport, request()->file('course'));
```

Comment: since you mentioned array, please kindly use toArray() instead of toCollection() like this; $row = Excel::toArray(new CourseImport, request()->file('course'));

Comment: Is there any way to optimize the toArray(). In case we have say 20k records in our request?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I achieved this:

In my UsersImport class: 
    namespace App\Imports;

```
use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;

class UsersImport implements ToModel
{
    use Importable;

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
           'id' => $row[0]
        ]);
    }
}
```

And in controller:

```
$imported_users = (new UsersImport)->toArray(request()->file('excel_file'))[0];
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create Import File using below command.

   php artisan make:import TestImport
2. Inside TestImport make changes like this:

   namespace App\Imports;

   use App\User;
   use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
   use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

   class TestImport implements ToCollection
   {
   public function collection(Collection $rows)
   {
   return $rows;
   }
   }
3. In Controller make changes like this:

   // original code:  $rows = Excel::import(new TestImport, 'test.xlsx');

   $rows = Excel::toCollection(new TestImport, 'test.xlsx');

Comment: ok so this `toArray` function came from [this docs](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/imports/concerns.html) I seen this but not understood. let me check you answer.

Comment: I think `load` method is no longer in version 3 I am getting error as `Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::load()`

Comment: check above again.

Comment: my problem is get array in controller not in TestImport

Comment: The answer had changed again it might fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate your dedication, but unfortunately your answer not worked for me, I am sharing my answer which worked for me.

Comment: This code doesn't work as expecter; if I try to access $row[0] I get this error: Cannot use object of type Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel as array

Comment: The code above returns a Laravel collection if you call $rows = Excel::toCollection(new TestImport, 'test.xlsx');  in the controller

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
$data = Excel::load($request->file('sampledata'), function ($reader) use($table) {
        $data = $reader->toArray();
        //here data has all excel data in array.
});
```

Comment: I am getting this error `"message": "Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Excel::load()",`

Comment: @NikleshRaut: Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473098/call-to-undefined-method-maatwebsite-excel-excelload)

Comment: @NikleshRaut: Yes something like that

Comment: unfortunately I knew about this thats why I asked here for version 3

Comment: @NikleshRaut: Okay

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am sharing my answer which worked for me.

Comment: This is for version 2, Laravel Excel Version 3 is completely different from previous version.